# event handling not working as expected nodejs

Tags: node.js

writing this little domain search app, it should sequentially search the .com of each item in an array, but it keeps searching for test1. even if I do a console log within the search function it tells me the value of x is test2, and test 3. do I need to remove the listener or something?

I get the following output

```
 domain test1.com

 Domain Name: TEST1.COM
 domain test2.com

 Domain Name: TEST1.COM
 domain test3.com

 Domain Name: TEST1.COM
```

app.js

```
 var port = 43;
 var net = require('net');
 var host = 'whois.internic.net';
 var dotCom = new net.Socket();
 var c = 0;
 var connections = 0;
 var dotComStatus;
 dotCom.setEncoding('ascii');

 var searches = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3'];
 search(searches.shift()); 

 function chkconnections(z) {
      if (connections <= 0) {
           if (searches.length >= 1) {
                process.nextTick(function() {
                     search(searches.shift());
                });
           }
      }
 }

function search(x) {
   var q = "domain " + x + ".com\r\n";

   dotCom.connect(port, host, function() {
        dotCom.write(q);
        console.log(q);
        connections++;
   });

   dotCom.on('data', function(data) {
        c++;
        if (c == 2) { 
             dotComStatus = data.split('\n')[1];
             dotCom.on('close', function() {
                  console.log(dotComStatus);
                  connections--;
                  chkconnections();
             });
        }
   });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several obvious problems with this code. Firstly putting the close event inside the data event is a bad idea. If the connection closed before data was received that section of code would never be reached.
Next is there is a big problem with the section with

```
c++;
if (c == 2)
```

Since you never reset `c` to 0 the next line `dotComStatus = data.split('\n')[1];` is never executed. But then the socket closes and the event `closed` is triggered. And this is executed again.

```
  console.log(dotComStatus);
  connections--;
  chkconnections();
```

But the value of `dotComStatus` has not changed since `c` was equal to 0. There are many examples of how to do this connect/data/end flow that is common in NodeJS.

```
 var port = 43;
  var net = require('net');
  var host = 'whois.internic.net';

  var searches = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3'];
  search(searches.shift());

  function chkconnections(z) {
    if(searches.length > 0)
      search(searches.shift());
  }

  function search(x) {
    var dotCom = new net.Socket();
    dotCom.setEncoding('ascii');
    var q = "domain " + x + ".com\r\n";

    dotCom.connect(port, host, function() {
      dotCom.write(q);
    });

    var data = ""; // holding place until socket closes

    dotCom.on('data', function(chunk) {
      data += chunk; // add chunk to data
    });

    dotCom.on("end", function() {
      // socket closed
      dotComStatus = data.split('\n')[7]; // Should be 'Domain Name: blah'
      console.log(dotComStatus);
      chkconnections(); // move on to next
    });
};
```